# Can Silverlight apps be embedded into PowerPoint?

Tags: flash, silverlight, powerpoint

Can Silverlight apps be embedded into PowerPoint?  We're currently weighing the pros and cons of Silverlight vs. Flash, and are primarily interested in charting controls.  The higher-ups would like to have aesthetically appealing dynamic charts included in PowerPoint presentations, with the ability to migrate these over to an online solution at a future time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All Silverlight apps need to be hosted in a browser, so you would need to get an HTML page in to your PPT.  This could probably be done by embedding a Winforms browser control in a page using VBA.

The XAP file and web page that hosts the Silverlight control(s) would need to be either hosted on an available web server, or the files placed locally on each PC that will run the presentation, which introduces additional dependencies.

Another problem you may have is to link the "dynamic charts" to data.  If you are able to have all the data be static and encapsulated inside your Silverlight controls then  this might be workable, but if you need to connect the charts to data in your powerpoint presentation, you could end up doing a lot of coding to get this to work.

**Long story short**, I would suggest that Silverlight is probably ***not*** the right tool for embedding visual content into PowerPoint.  It is really expressly designed for online/web deployment.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it would need to be hosted on an IIS server?  AFAIK, if the browser can be pointed to a local file, all that it would require is the html and .xap file.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I had never tried this.  That makes it a bit more palatable.  You would still need to manage the HTML and XAP files that were referenced by your PPT locally, of course.  I am editing the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I came here when I searched for "Hosting Silverlight app in powerpoint".  My usecase was to provide conduct a quick poll going around the room and clicking on a button to increase the bars.  So people can really see the results as the poll progresses.   http://www.turningtechnologies.com/studentresponsesystem/studentresponsesolutions/turningpoint/